# Magento Fedex set Base Currency

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods, fedex

We are using 1.9.3.1 with follwing fedex settings

```
Product Weight : 0.5 kg
Service type : International Priority
Shipping Origin : UAE
Shipping Destination : USA
```

Our Shipping Fedex account is opened in Dubai. So all the amount is calculated in `AED`.

The problem is system base currency is setup as `EURO` and according to current fedex behaviour shipping amount is calculated based on shipping account origin.

So we are getting response in `AED` which Magento assumes as `base currency (EURO)` which results wrong calculation.

One solution I got from other resources is to set the base currency of Magento to `AED` but its a Multistore Website with different currency setup and its live.

Is there any other solution for this or I have to override `Fedex Modal` and covert the `base currency(EURO)` to `AED` on `request` and `AED` to `base currency(EURO)` on `response` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the base currency seems to be the best solution but unfortunately we cant do it.

So I changed the request price from `Euro` to `AED` and then again in response object changed `AED` to `EURO`.

This is the file that I overide in local `app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php`.

So Basically in this file `_formRateRequest` method sends the rate request to fedex for fetching the shipping price and sends some params like

```
[DropoffType] => REQUEST_COURIER
[PackagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
[ServiceType] => STANDARD_OVERNIGHT
[TotalInsuredValue] => Array
(
   [Amount] => 2200 // Convert this to EURO to AED
   [Currency] => DHS // Convert this to DHS
)
```

And then `_prepareRateResponse` this method where I changes the price for shipping rate response back to `Euro` from `AED`.

```
    /* customization */
      $baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
      $price = $this->convertCurrencyToBase($baseCurrencyCode,self::LOCAL_COUNTRY_CODE_ORIGINAL,$price);
   /* customization */
    $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
    ....
```

We can get code of `convertCurrencyToBase` from anywhere.

And at last I also set same price in `_parseXmlResponse` method which prepares shipping rate after payment.

Answer (score 1):

Its better if we override the modal class of modules.

You can get the tutorials of module override here

https://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

In your sceneraio

`app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php`

should be overided.